# Is every type of evolution stone equally distributed in the Underground?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

I noticed on my *Pokémon Platinum* cartridge that I have far fewer Water Stones in my inventory than any other type of evolution stone. I have around 30 Fire Stones and 20 Thunderstones, but only 2 Water Stones.

Now, I'm a fan of Vaporeon, but I don't remember going on a Water Stone spree. Is there any reason that Water Stones would be less common in the Underground? Does it vary by game or player ID? Does it vary by area? Do some games get no stones of a certain type, the same way some Pokémon are version-exclusive to encourage trading?

Answer (score 1):

The straight answer is that the RNG (Random Number Generator) just hasn't given you as many Water Stones as it has Fire and Thunder. They all have the same chance to appear, with an increased chance for all of them after you get the National Dex.

Comment: This effect is why it's called a "Pseudo Random Number Generator".